Har Sinai and the Kodesh HaKodashim
In the sefer "Yad Avraham" by Rabbi Yechiel Tenzer (Makhshirin, p. 47 sv. אי אפשר לבית המדרש בלי חידוש), a Ramban is cited that says that Har Sinai, and the boundaries G-d set up, refer to the Holy of Holies.
I.e. boundaries referred to in these verses (Shemos 19:12-13):

And thou shalt set bounds to the people round about, saying, Take heed to yourselves, that you go not up into the mountain, or touch the border of it: whoever touches the mountain shall be surely put to death:


no hand shall touch him, but he shall surely be stoned, or shot through; whether it be beast or man, it shall not live: when the horn sounds long, they shall come up to the mountain.

Does anyone know where to find the quoted Ramban, comparing the mountain and its boundaries to the Holy of Holies, and if there are other meforshim that make this connection?
The sefer Yayin Yashan mentions the Ramban's introduction to sefer Shemos, but there he writes:

When they came to Mount Sinai and made the Tabernacle, and the Holy One, blessed be He, caused His Divine Presence to dwell again amongst them, they returned to the status of their fathers when the ‘sod eloka’ (counsel of G-d) was upon their tents and “they were those who constituted the Chariot of the Holy One.”

But this does not say that Har Sinai refers to the Kodesh HaKodeshim.....

I don't see R. Tenzer refer to boundaries, but as to the Ramban connecting Sinai to the Mishkan/Qodesh ha-Qodashim see his intro to Terumah
